# Getter and Setter Explained?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am just learning OOP from a book I picked up (Big Nerd Ranch), and it just went through the getter and setter chapter. I would just like to clarify I understand what I have just done. Instead of creating a method to set the value of an instance, and then another method to extract the value and display it, I create use the `@property` and `@synthesize` syntax to define both methods.

Instead of doing this:

```
-(void) setHeightOfObject:(int)h;
-(void) setWeightOfObject:(float)w;
-(int) heightOfObject;
-(float) weightOfObject;
```

and defining it like this:

```
- (int)heightOfObject
{
    return heightOfObject;
}

- (void)setHeightOfObject:(int)h
{
    heightInMeters = h;
}

- (float)weightOfObject
{
    return weightOfObject;
}

- (void)setWeightOfObject:(float)w
{
    weightOfObject = w;
}
```

I would do this with getter and setters in the .h file:

```
@property int heightOfObject;
@property float weightOfObject;
```

And then go to my .m file and link it:

```
@synthesize heightInMeters, weightOfObject;
```

This then gives me the ability to set the value of my object, and then get it if I need it printed? I know this is an important concept and I want to make sure I have the proper grasp of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. The `@synthesize` essential expands out to the implementation you wrote while compiling.

Since writing getters and setters is boring and repetitive (and most objects have a bunch of properties you'd want getters and setters for) having this little shortcut makes you spend less time on [boilerplate code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) and more time implementing something interesting.

If you'd like more detailed information about objective-c's properties, you can have a look at the [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) (although this might be somewhat unnecessarily detailed for you at this point).

Comment: Awesome, I will check out the link later on in my programming journey

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to what you are achieving by using @property and @synthesize.

@property tells the compiler that it should allow you to use dot syntax to call the accessors of heightOfObject and weightOfObject. So doing this

```
int height = myObject.heightOfObject;
myObject.weightOfObject = 10;
```

becomes legal code and is exactly equivalent to this:

```
int height = [myObject heightOfObject];
[myObject setWeightOfObject:10];
```

You can use @property without @synthesize, in which case you must implement the accessors exactly as you have done in your question.

Using @synthesize tells the compiler that it should generate the accessors for you and it will also generate the instance variables themselves if your runtime supports it (e.g. on iOS and 64-bit OS X).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Property and synthesise were introduced in Objective C 2.0 in order to provide a straightforward way to create getters and setters.

Check this link it will be of help:

http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103

Answer (score 0):

You not only get getters and setters. You also get a neat syntax: self.heightOfObject which you can assign to or read from.
@property has a lot of settings though so you might want to read in detail. In particular you can control whether you need both read and write access or only one of them.